# With two rewrite rules for different directories, only one works

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

### Background

I'm trying to add another rewrite rule for my Apache server but am having a strange issue.

This new rule which I'm creating causes the original rule to break (as in, not work... I don't get any errors). Only one or the other rule will run.

It's easier to explain by showing the code...

### Code

Rule #1:

```
# Redirect hits from non-existent page to link shortener
<Directory /var/www/html/lnf>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [L]

RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ link/link.php?a=$1 [L]
</Directory>
```

Rule #2:

```
# Deny disallowed user agents (when adding this, it causes the first one to break)
<Directory ~ "/var/www/html/*">
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "(netscape|\.ru)" [nocase]
RewriteRule ^.*$ – [forbidden,last]
</Directory>
```

### Question

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

PS: Excuse my lack of knowledge, I still feel like a beginner when it comes to Apache.

### Update

I have 4 vhosts for HTTP and 4 for HTTPS.

The four in both `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` and `/default-ssl.conf` are:

1. A catch-all for denying all hits to the public IP which are usually bots (This is on the top of the vhosts file to catch if nothing else does):

```
<VirtualHost *:80 (and 443 in ssl)>
    ServerName catchall
    <Location />
        Require all denied
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

2. 3 different vhosts for 3 different domains

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80 (and 443 in ssl)>
ServerName (my domain)

### REDIRECT HTTP TO HTTPS (this is only in the 000-default.conf)
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#only change when using [mydomain.com] domain (the only public domain)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

# doc roots, error logs, ssl certificates (I omitted this to save space)
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have it this way:

```
# default rule applied to all locations
<Location />
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "(netscape|\.ru)" [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ – [F,L]
</Location>

# catch all virtual host
<VirtualHost _default_:*>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName catchall
    <Location />
        Require all denied
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>

# rules specific to mydomain.com placed here
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/lnf"
    ServerName mydomain.com
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    ### REDIRECT HTTP TO HTTPS (this is only in the 000-default.conf)
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    #only change when using [mydomain.com] domain (the only public domain)
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/?$ /link/link.php?a=$1 [L,QSA]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Oops... I see. I changed the regex to what you said and it does work, but that isn't the issue... By using this, the rule before it "Redirecting hits from non-existent page to link shortener" does not work... Instead I get a standard 404 not found...

Comment: I'll try, but I don't mean the rule that you wrote... The one above it is supposed to redirect non-existing directories to a php script with the directory as a parameter... This is just resulting in a 404 when the rule below it (the one you tweaked) is placed in the file...

Comment: DocRoot: `/var/www/html/lnf/` full path: `/var/www/html/lnf/link/link.php`... I tried switching the order of the rules as appearing in my question in reverse, but the same happened... The link shortener rule doesn't work when the other rule exists...

Comment: I numbered the rules for clarity... I put rule#2 above rule#1, but rule#1 only works if rule#2 isn't there...

Comment: Thank you, this works correctly except rule#2 is supposed to work on all the domains which I host... Is there possibly a way to do this? (That's what the regex was for...)

Comment: Yeah... `404 not found` on going to `mydomain.com/adirectory`

Comment: I've updated my answer. I've used all `VirtualHost` sections for rules. There is no `<Directory>` section. I've tested it on my Apache and it all works fine.